# jQuery Cycle - randomizing multiple elements in sync

Tags: jquery, random, nested, synchronization, cycle

I am trying to cycle the content of two elements on a page in random order but synced to each other.

I have two div containers with a set of nested divs:

```
(div class=text (.textA, .textB, .textC)), (div class=image (.imageA, .imageB, .imageC))
```

I am using this to start the simultaneous transition:

```
$('.text, .image').cycle({
    fx:    'fade',
    delay: -2000,
    speed:  'slow',
    random: 1
});
```

but I get always other order in both div-elements: `(.text .textB) -> (.image .imageA)` and so on.

How do I get the both nested elements to display in sync?

Answer (score 0):

Only set the cycle on one of the slideshows; then use the `after` callback to transition the other one to the corresponding slide:

```
after: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
    // your code here
}
```